# Would the clones be emotionally and mentally the same as the original?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-prestige

In the movie *The Prestige*, Angier, with the help of Tesla, introduces a machine that can clone whatever falls into it in his performance. However, we also know that the original Angier might have ended up either in the water tank or as The Prestige of the performance.

We know the clones looked perfectly similar to the original; however, were the clones mentally and emotionally exactly the same as the original? In this sense, would the clone know the original Angier's past, his entire story with Borden and Julia, and the strain and enemity?

In the last confrontation scene between Borden and Angier at the old magic hall (where Angier stores his clones in water tanks), the Angier talking to Borden is a clone, but the confrontation happens like it's between Borden and the original Angier, as if the clone knew everything that happened in the past, as if he had first-hand faced the betrayal and witnessed Julia's death. As if the clone knows the whole story and reason for ending up being shot by Borden.

[image: screencap of the scene described above]
[image: screencap of the scene described above]

Comment: "the Angier talking to Borden is a clone" -- says who?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The clones know and feel everything exactly the same as the original.

It is the only way that makes Angier unsure of whether he is the original or not. We know they are exactly the same because he kills on different occasions the new clone and the original one.

**If the clones didn't feel or think exactly the same, then Angier would have eventually known if he was the Prestige or the one falling in the water tank**.

Comment: Also, since the first time he performs it he kills the one in the stands and in future performances kills the one at the stage, then the ones created in the stands must have all those memories or the plan would never be followed up on.  I love the movie but kind of hate this - from the original's perspective he killed a copy/clone in the stands the first time, but every time after that he kills "himself."  He acted on blind faith that the stands-copy would be exactly like him and continue his vendetta with Borden.

Comment: @sirjonsnow: But if the clones are indistinguishable from the original, how can we know that the original isn't teleported to the stands? It makes as much sense that Angier teleports and an imprint remains. In that case, it was the _first clone_ (the one who stayed on the stage) who killed Angiers (in the stands), and who has kept killing the next clones (because he then kills the new clones on stage). There could be a _single_ killer out there. The first clone, who both knew that Angiers would kill him and can prevent future clones from doing the same to him by immediately drowning them.

Comment: @Flater - to me, the reaction of the one on the stage the first time it happens is that he hasn't moved at all and a copy appeared in the stands.  Your example would be an interesting case, but I don't think they tried to imply that.  But, this is all subjective.

Comment: @sirjonsnow: I think the key here is the reaction of the one on stage the **first** time. Angier never performed the trick before, he didn't know what to expect. Both original Angier and clone Angier will think they are the original Angier (since there is no way to tell the difference and both men remember everything from before the cloning), so their initial surprise reaction would have been the same regardless of who is the clone.

Comment: @Flater - yes, that's my point.  To the one on stage he's "real" and the other must be a clone, fake, whatever.  So it's pretty nuts (IMO) to then set the trick so the one at the stage will die and you're counting on the other to also be a "real" you and continue the plan.  It would make more sense to me if the stands version killed the stage version the first time - I'm in the stands now, so I don't care if I kill that stage version of me every time.

Comment: @sirjonsnow: `So it's pretty nuts (IMO) to then set the trick so the one at the stage will die` So we circle back to my "first clone is the killer" theory. The movie isn't particularly suggesting this, but it would make only one of the Angiers (the first clone) a killer, while the others are all victims. Also, note that if both Angiers (from a single cloning action) are **indistinguishable**, then either Angiers could argue that the other Angiers is the one that should be killed. I think Angiers intentionally prevents this by **immediately** killing one of them (the one on stage).

Comment: @Flater - I think you missed my point.  The first time the one at the stage lives, from his perspective he didn't teleport or anything, so when doing this trick he (again, from his perspective) will be the one on stage, and the one in the stands a copy.  But he chooses to kill the stage version from then on, I think that's quite a leap of logic for him.  If you or I experienced this, I don't think either of us would then say, "Let me rig a trap under this, so next time I die and the copy of me in the stands can continue my work."

Comment: @sirjonsnow: For the purposes of the trick, the Angiers on stage needed to disappear (from sight) anyway. Angiers 1 (original) and Angiers 2 (first clone) both realized that the other was going to kill them, and it was a struggle. Whichever Angiers survived the first killing; **he** knew that this would happen every single time. And every time it happened, both Angiers would be aware of how they managed to kill their opponent all of the previous times (because they retain memories). By immediately killing off one Angiers, he therefore prevents them from being able to retaliate.

Comment: @sirjonsnow: To make sure I'm clear: What I mean is that if Angiers is pragmatic enough to realize that _either_ of them could be considered the "real" Angiers, that means that it doesn't really matter which one gets killed. The only thing that could still be an issue is if **during the struggle to kill eachother**, the Angiers get seen by the public.This would ruin the trick, kill the show, and foil the plan to frame Borden (since there will be no more magic show for Borden to visit). So therefore, Angiers makes the pragmatic choice to guarantee one clone's death to prevent a struggle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59011/discussion-between-sirjonsnow-and-flater).

Answer (score 13):

They aren't *clones*, they are **duplicates** created by Tesla's machine.

Since they **exactly** the same person as at the time the duplicate was created they would have all the same memories and experiences as the original and thus feel and act the same way *as* the original.

Answer (score 0):

I think the film version makes it seems like they are one in the same, especially since the film does not give the time to explore 'nature and nurture' argument from the point of creation, but the novel makes it much more of a debate. And so this answer may be marginally relative for those that wonder about the possibility, since it DOES exist as a point of interest in source material.

Like many film adaptations *The Prestige* is, in some ways, a watered-down version of the novel, as the novel explores the duplicates a bit further, and in a slightly different way than the film does.

Instead of the clones being "corporeal" like the original Angier, they are incorporeal--ghost-like images. The novel ends with the incorporeal Angier **reuniting** with the corporeal one, whose dying with the hopes to use Tesla's machine to transport himself into the dead body of the original Angier! But the following paragraph from Wikipedia about a plot with incorporeal Angier and one of the Bordens makes clear that the incorporeal one does not follow through, because of his **sense of morality**--so one could argue that the incorporeal duplicate, may be more moral than the original Angier, depending if one views Angier as amoral.

> The duplicate Angier, **alienated from the world** by his ghostly form,
>   discovers Borden's secret. He attacks one of the twins before a
>   performance. **However, Borden's apparent poor health and the duplicate
>   Angier's sense of morality prevent the assault from becoming murder.**
>   It is implied that this particular Borden dies a few days later, and
>   the incorporeal Angier travels to meet the corporeal Angier, now
>   living as the 14th Earl of Colderdale. They obtain Borden's diary and
>   publish it without revealing the twins' secret. Shortly afterwards,
>   the corporeal Angier dies and his ghostly clone uses Tesla's device to
>   teleport himself into the body, hoping that either he will reanimate
>   it and be whole again, or kill himself instantly. It is revealed in
>   the final chapter that some form of Angier has continued to survive to
>   the present day. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prestige